# TTS Voice Cloning

Tags: python, linux, deep-learning, nlp, text-to-speech

I have used coqui's open-source repository to build a voice clone model. It makes use of different tts_models trained using LJSpeech datasets. I used the multilingual model to use the sample that I have provided. However, I have been getting this error:

ValueError:  [!] Look like you use a multi-lingual model. You need to define either a `language_name` or a `style_wav` to use a multi-lingual model.

I have used Google colab's virtual environment for this as Coqui is developed for Linux.

Here's my code:

```
!git clone https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS
!pip install TTS
!sudo apt-get install espeak-ng
!pip install IPython

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/TTS')

!cd TTS

!ls

!tts --list_models

!python -c 'from TTS.utils.downloaders import download_ljspeech; download_ljspeech("/content/drive/MyDrive/TTS/recipes/ljspeech/");'

!tts --text "The economy suffered a great deal." \
    --model_name "tts_models/multilingual/multi-dataset/your_tts" --speaker_wav "/content/drive/MyDrive/TTS/recipes/ljspeech/LJSpeech-1.1/Sample.wav"  --out_path /content/drive/MyDrive/TTS/output.wav

from IPython.display import Audio
display(Audio('/content/drive/MyDrive/TTS/output.wav'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:
--language_idx="en"